# Quotation marks with indirect quote

Tags: quotation-marks

Is a comma required after "quiet" in the following sentence, as if it were a direct quote?  And if no, does "Yes" need to be capitalized?

Margaret curtseyed and spoke a quiet “Yes, ma’am.”

Answer (score 1):

The comma is not required, because the quoted phrase is not used as dialog but as the object of the speaking action.

For a detailed list of similar examples, see [this blog](https://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/commas-before-quotes/).

I would keep the capitalization of "Yes," since that is the correct capitalization of the phrase Margaret uttered.